# Eclipse search for perfect match (regex)?

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

In eclipse its possible to do a file search Ctrl+H. I need to do this but it must only return a perfect match like 'com.company.base' and not all strings that have this as a prefix, eg.

com.company.base.model
com.company.base.db
com.company.base.ui
etc.

I have tried to enable the regex option but am not sure how to formulate that it should be a perfect match. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
\scom\.company\.base\s
```

You need to escape the `.` - otherwise it means any character. `\s` means white space.

Answer (score 0):

What about searching for `com.company.base` where the next character is *not* a dot?

```
com.company.base[^.]
```